# How to extract the version from the name of a NuGet package file using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, nuget

I have a file that contains the name of the nuget package like `rmp2.<version>.nupkg`. I want to take the `<version>` part alone. I have tried many things.
One such snippet is below:

```
Get-Content version.txt | ForEach-Object { $_.split("nupkg")[1]} | cut -f 2,3 -d 2
```

It is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is not working because of the dot at the end of version, try this:

```
$version = Get-Content version.txt | ForEach-Object { $_.split("nupkg")[1]}

$version.Substring(0,$version.Length-1)
```

or try using -split instead of .split

```
(((Get-Content version.txt) -split('.nupkg')) -split('rmp2.'))[1]
```

Comment: it is including the 2 as well. I am getting the output as 2.<version>

Comment: Working. Although I had another shortcut of something like this.
```$version.Substring(2)```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regular expression to pick up various other package ids and versions. e.g.

- my.package.net.10.0.0.nupkg
- my.package.net.10.0.nupkg
- my.package.editor.csharp.0.1-build000055.nupkg
- my.package.4.0.0.editor.csharp.0.1-build000055.nupkg
- my.package.4.0.0.editor.csharp.0.1.0-build000055.nupkg

```
if ($file.Name -match '(?<=(?<id>.+))\.(?<version>((\d+\.\d+(\.\d+)?))(?<suffix>(-.*)?))\.nupkg')
{
    $packageId = $Matches.id
    $packageVersion = $Matches.version
    # do your thing
}
```